# Using multer with nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, upload, multer

I am trying to upload a file from my page to node server.

I can see form data are arriving in the router on server.

But no file is saved in upload folder.

What am I doing wrong?

//router unit

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log('chegei')
        cb(null, "uploads/")
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log('chegei2')
        cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.ogirinalname)
    },
});

module.exports = function (page) {
     router.post('/SendMsgBase64', async (req, res) => {
        var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('userFile');
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send({ "data": "Error uploading file." });
            }
            return res.send({ "data": "File is uploaded" });
        });  
  return router
}
```

//app.js unit

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const WARoutes = require('../routes/WARoutes');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
})
app.use('/whats', WARoutes(this.page));
```

//html

```
  <form id="uploadForm">
      <input type="file" name="userFile" />
      <input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadFile();">
      <span id="status"></span>
    </form>

    <script>
      uploadFile = () => {
        var formData = new FormData();
        debugger
        var logoImg = $('input[name="userFile"]').get(0).files[0];

        formData.append('logo', logoImg);
        var objArr = [];

        objArr.push({ "id": "123", "name": "luiz" });

        //JSON obj
        formData.append('objArr', JSON.stringify(objArr));

        $.ajax({
          url: "/whats/SendMsgBase64",
          type: "POST",
          processData: false,
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          data: formData,
          complete: function (data) {
            alert("success");
          }
        })
      };    
    </script>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, I would check the syntax. You misspelled file.originalname and have an extra comma at the end of your storage declaration. If that doesn't work, maybe get rid of the "/" in front of "uploads" file destination (also in your storage declaration). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to multer's github page, if you have not created the uploads directory, it may go something wrong.
If this is the case, creating the directory on your own or passing a string value to destination property is the solution for you.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

> Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you.